# Connection with database Doctrine PDO

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using Zend framework with Doctrine, and i am transfering from localhost to my server, but i receve this error. Everything is working well localy.

```
Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] No such file or directory 
(trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock) in /www/webvol19/94/yi8ghefpta7q527/
mywebsite.com/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 36
```

My connection settings are these:

```
// pdo connection definition

'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=dbname123;host=mysql410.ddd.com',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass121512',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
),

// doctrine connection definition
'doctrine_config' => array (
    'proxy_directory' => APP_PATH 
                         . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 
                         . 'data'
                         . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
                         . 'Doctrineproxy',
    'proxy_namespace' => 'Doctrineproxy',
    'doctrine_db_conn_params' => array (
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user'     => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass121512',
        'dbname'   => 'dbname123',
    ),
    'is_dev_mode' => true,
),
```

i am not sure what is this before my website name

```
/www/webvol19/94/yi8ghefpta7q527/
```

Comment: Is mysql up and running on server? If yes how it's configured? is mysql listening a local or external ip or socket file? is /tmp/mysql.sock file exists?

Comment: Try to use host with something like localhost or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you transferring from localhost to your server but application still connects to localhost.

Doctrine config include its own database parameters and independent from outside predefined database configuraiton. In your case you must to point host and (optionally) port inside `'doctrine_config'`:

```
'doctrine_config' => array (
    ...
    'doctrine_db_conn_params' => array (
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user'     => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass121512',
        'dbname'   => 'dbname123',
        /* add this */
        'host' => 'mysql410.ddd.com',
        //'port' => 3306
    ),
    ...
),
```